# Trouble installing python using terminal

Tags: python, installation, sudo

I followed these steps in trying to install python but then all of a sudden my terminal won't open. What might be the problem and how can I fix it?

```sh
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install python3.6
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.5 1

sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.6 2
sudo update-alternatives --config python3
sudo rm /usr/bin/python3

sudo ln -s python3.5 /usr/bin/python3
```

Comment: Where did you get these "steps"?  Which distro are you using?

Comment: Are you by any chance on Ubuntu 16 and trying to launch `gnome-terminal`? If so, try launching `xterm` instead and from `xterm` type `gnome-terminal` and see if you have python errors.

Comment: @MFisherKDX this is the kind of error am getting ImportError: No module named 'apt_pkg'

Comment: i assume if you type `head /usr/bin/gnome-terminal` you see the shebang `#/usr/bin/python3`.  If you edit this file (`sudo nano /usr/bin/gnome-terminal`) and change to `#/usr/bin/python3` to `#/usr/bin/python3.5` does the terminal work?  Note: this is a hack and not really the right solution.  I am interested in how to solve it correctly.  If you figure out how to actually solve this correctly, please post an answer here.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect problem in this line:

```
sudo ln -s python3.5 /usr/bin/python3
```

Did you execute it from the directory with a python3.5 binary?